# jQuery UI button not working in IE

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have some jQuery UI buttons inside an  tag

```
<div class="comprarnow">
  <a href="http://buy-it.com.ar/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&amp;products_id=2&amp;osCsid=f4ef2fde10273a05bab1076209809e80">
    <span class="jqueryui">
      <button id="tdb1" type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
      <span class="ui-button-text"> COMPRAR AHORA </span>
      </button>
    </span>
   <script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb1").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-cart"}}).parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script></a></div>
```

The buttons work and look great in all browsers except IE. The button is inside a simple  tag which has its href value so I'm clueless on why if I click it, NOTHING happens, not even in the javascript error console, nothing...

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just for clarity, what version of IE?

Comment: What is the doctype of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the markup you're actually putting on your page, or the generated markup that you see after running the page? You're not supposed to use all the class="ui-*" stuff; that's supposed to be generated for you. Putting a button (and a script tag as well, I just noticed you put the `</a></div>` at the very end of this code sample) inside an anchor is really odd as well -- jQuery UI is made for you to instantiate buttons on anchor or button or input elements with the same visual results... Why wouldn't you just do this?

```
<a id="tdb1" href="http://buy-it.com.ar/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&amp;products_id=2&amp;osCsid=f4ef2fde10273a05bab1076209809e80">COMPRAR AHORA</a>

<script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb1").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-cart"}})</script>
```

Comment: I used that markup because each button is generated by a php function tht generates a <script> tag for every button. I optimized the loop and made only one script with a class selector to the <a> and not to the <button> and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you are importing the necessary jquery files
- Change:
  $("#tdb1").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-cart"}}).parent().removeClass("tdbLink");
  to
  $(function() {
        $("#tdb1").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-cart"}}).parent().removeClass("tdbLink");
  });